# Is there no compton shift when free electron collides with energetic photon heads on?

Tags: photons, electrons, collision

Because free electron cannot emit or absorb photon due to conservation of energy and momentum, anyhow I just like to know can there be no change in the frequency of the photon after the scattering? if so wouldn't that violate newton third law?

Comment: That is called Thompson scattering. It is the scattering of light by a free charged particle when the energy of the photon is much less than the energy of the particle.
Compton scattering is defined as the innelastic collision between a photon and a charged particle, so by definition there is a compton shift however small.

Comment: If the energy of the photon is much greater than the energy of the charged particle, the photon will be scattered backwards (at $\theta=\pi$) and its energy after the collision will be independent of its initial energy. More exactly, its energy will be $E=\frac{mc^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the photon is scattered by an angle $\theta$:

[image: Compton scattering]

Then we can use the conservation of momentum and energy to calculate the momentum and energy after scattering of both the photon and electron. The result is [the well known equation for the wavelength of the photon after scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering#Description_of_the_phenomenon):

$$ \lambda' = \lambda + \frac{h}{mc} \left( 1 - \cos\theta \right) \tag{1} $$

where $m$ is the mass of the particle doing the scattering.

You don't say exactly what you mean by a head on collision, but for the photon to be completely absorbed the value of $\lambda'$ would have to go to infinity and this never happens because for all values of $\theta$ the right hand side of equation (1) remains finite. So the photon can never be completely absorbed just like an isolated electron can never emit a single photon.

The case where the photon wavelength is unchanged is when $\theta=0$ i.e. when the photon carries straight on without transferring any energy or momentum to the electron.